# Gson - Unparseable date

Tags: java, gson

I have to bind a Json object with a java object that has a Date. The Date format on my Json is the following:

2013-01-04T10:50:26+0000

And I'm using the GsonBulder as follow:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ").create();
```

but Im getting the following exception:

```
The RuntimeException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: 2013-01-04T10:50:26+0000
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.DateTypeAdapter.deserializeToDate(DateTypeAdapter.java:81)
.....
Caused by: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2013-01-04T10:50:26+0000"
at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:337)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.DateTypeAdapter.deserializeToDate(DateTypeAdapter.java:79)
```

I'm trying to load this request with Gson:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=id,username,email,link,updated_time&access_token=accessToken
```

And the response is

```
{"id":"12345","username":"myusername","email":"myemail\u0040yahoo.it","link":"http:\/\/www.facebook.com\/mysusername","updated_time":"2013-01-04T10:50:26+0000"}
```

Comment: Where does the time string (`2013-01-04T10:50:26+0000`) come from?

Comment: I updated the question, please have a look at it.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The Deserialization fails, because the quotes within the json String are missing.

The following works:

```
    Gson gson=  new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ").create();

    String date = "\"2013-02-10T13:45:30+0100\"";
    Date test = gson.fromJson(date, Date.class);
    System.out.println("date:" + test);
```

Output:

> date:Sun Feb 10 13:45:30 CET 2013

HTH

**Edit Complete Example:**

```
import java.util.Date;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;


public class FacebookResponse {

int id;
String username;
String email;
String link;
Date updated_time;

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "ID: " + id + " username: " + username + " email: " + email + " link: " + link + " updated_time: " + updated_time;
};



/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {        
    String json = "{\"id\":\"12345\",\"username\":\"myusername\",\"email\":\"myemail\u0040yahoo.it\",\"link\":\"http://www.facebook.com/mysusername\",\"updated_time\":\"2013-01-04T10:50:26+0000\"}";
    Gson gson=  new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ").create();

    FacebookResponse response = gson.fromJson(json, FacebookResponse.class);
    System.out.println(response);
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks Dominik, at the end my code was working but I was testing the code with a bad formed json. Thanks for the feedback

Comment: Is there a way to tell the setDateFormat method to add the missing quotes, or would I have to write a custom DateAdapter for that?

Answer (score -1):

```
@PUT
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response put(@HeaderParam
                    final String userFromString,
                    @Context final HttpServletRequest req) {

    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(userFromString);
    ReturnCode resultCode = null;
    UserDto user= new UserDto();
    Gson gson=  new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").create();
    user= gson.fromJson(userFromString,UserDto.class);
```

Comment: starting form this error "java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date "

passing jsonObj with rest by backbone save method "

Comment: The answer is not useful because the question is about bind a Json object with a date/time field, not only a date field

Comment: starting from the example of dominik with mine you can know now that not only his solution plays but a  variation of it's solution too , hence ,you can use the format you like ,since  the real important thing is that you have to choose and set it before.May be it can be useful to know that this problem i had with jboss 7.x server , not with 6.x : the serialization seems not to be  necessary with 6.x